# Allow dot in url htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently i got "Not found" while i am using "." in the URL, ex:

```
  track/amxvb3BqbG9pbQ==/bg==/&order_amount=900.12
```

How can i allow it to use "."?

My code is:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3&page4=$4
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3&page4=$4&page5=$5
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1` < Well, then remove the `\.` here!?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules seem to be faulty here. Replace all of your rules with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3&page4=$4&page5=$5 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3&page4=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&page2=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And remember always keep these rules in the **order of most specific to most generic**.