# Dot not allowed between the url in .htaccess in opencart

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

I have been trying to include dot in my url but .htaccess RewriteRule is not helping me to do so.
I have been using the following expression

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]) index.php?id=$1&route=$2 [L,QSA]
```

while this allows me to add a dot at the end of url it doesnt allow me to do so in between the url.

for eg if i use 
    `http://localhost/opencart/user/vendor_name.`

it doesnot give an error but if i use
    `http://localhost/opencart/user/vendor.name`

it gives an error of page not found.

Can anyone give me an expression that will allow me to do so.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168099/allow-dot-in-url-htaccess

Comment: No idea how any of this is working, assuming the htaccess file is in the "opencart" directory, the URI `user/vendor_name.` won't ever match `^user/(\w+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_\.])`. There's only one slash in the URI and there's 2 slashes in the regex pattern.

Comment: thanks alot Shankar using [^/] works perfectly in my case

Comment: Jon the problem was with the (\w+) that is the second parameter.
Problem is solved. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your regex is wrong. `[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]` will match only single dot after slash.

Try this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/[-\w.]+)/([-\w.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&route=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Nope, not true. DOT doesn't need escaping inside character class. `-` also doesn't need escaping if placed at first or last position in a character class.